# ASP.net OleDbCommand Oracle SQL not returning any results with valid query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

I am trying to read the results from an SQL query using OleDbCommand in ASP.net with C# codebehind. I am using the following Oracle SQL statement which is valid and works properly within Oracle SQL Developer:

```
WITH "bis" AS
    (SELECT v.name AS "vendor", 
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "bi5", 
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "bi6", 
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "bi7" 
    FROM incident_tbl i, vendor_tbl v 
    WHERE i.vendor_code=v.vendor_code 
    GROUP BY v.name 
    ORDER BY v.name) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "bis"."vendor", 
    "bis"."bi5", 
    "bis"."bi6", 
    "bis"."bi7", 
    ("bis"."bi5"+"bis"."bi6"+"bis"."bi7") AS "total" 
FROM "bis" 
WHERE "vendor"!='[No Vendor]' 
ORDER BY "total" DESC
```

This produces a correct result of 92 rows. However when I run it on my ASP.net page, it returns zero rows. I even isolated the query into a test method to try and sort it out:
(`con` is an already-existing working connection string)

```
protected void test()
    {
        OleDbCommand sql = new OleDbCommand("WITH \"bis\" AS (SELECT v.name AS \"vendor\", SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS \"bi5\", SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS \"bi6\", SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS \"bi7\" FROM incident_tbl i, vendor_tbl v WHERE i.vendor_code=v.vendor_code GROUP BY v.name ORDER BY v.name) SELECT DISTINCT \"bis\".\"vendor\", \"bis\".\"bi5\", \"bis\".\"bi6\", \"bis\".\"bi7\", (\"bis\".\"bi5\"+\"bis\".\"bi6\"+\"bis\".\"bi7\") AS \"total\" FROM incident_tbl i, \"bis\" WHERE \"vendor\"!='[No Vendor]' ORDER BY \"total\" DESC", con);
        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Show on a temporary label for testing
                lblDebug.Text += "<br />New row... vendor: " + reader["vendor"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblDebug.Text += "<br />ERROR WITH TEST METHOD: " + ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
    }
```

The thing is, no exceptions are thrown, there are just zero results.
Any ideas?

Comment: ...unrelated - but why `FROM incident_tbl i, "bis"`? You are using only `"bis"`, not `incident_tbl`

Comment: @MiMo You're right, it's not needed. It's left over from when I was building the query so I have now removed it. (Still doesn't work, but that was a very long shot ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
  vendor,  
  bi5,  
  bi6,  
  bi7,  
  (bi5+bi6+bi7) total  
FROM  
  (SELECT v.name vendor,  
   SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) bi5,  
   SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) bi6,  
   SUM(CASE WHEN i.bi_rating=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) bi7  
   FROM incident_tbl i, vendor_tbl v  
   WHERE i.vendor_code=v.vendor_code  
   GROUP BY v.name  
   ORDER BY v.name) bis
WHERE vendor!='[No Vendor]'  
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Success! Thanks, this produces the exact same results as my query in the question, but works in the code! I understand the changes in the query, but is there any reasoning as to why it wasn't working before? Or was it just a guess? :-)

Comment: ..a guess. I recently had a different problem in a query `with T as . . .` executed from Ole DB and I solved it switching to `select ...from` - I guessed it was a similar problem.

Comment: Weird, maybe ASP.net only likes `SELECT` statements that start only with `SELECT` or something... But at least it's solved, thanks again :-)